# React app installation issue on Linux mint PC

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux

[code screenshot  &](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71kfA.png)  [see I am using latest version of node and npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzobY.png)

When I run npx create-react-app folder-name then it ends with below message in bold  highlight .
"Note: the project was bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools. Please update to Node >=14 and npm >=6 to get supported tools in new projects".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, no idea why!

Comment: @HotSauceCoconuts I got solved automatically. Still do you face the same?

Comment: I can't quite remember but think my issue was caused by a wrong version of node. I had both a regular install and a version install with nvm (think that's the version manager name) and after uninstalling node with snap, create-react-app used the nvm version instead.